# How to use react native for windows emulator support both for android and ios Like mac

Tags: react-native

React native for windows emulator support both for android and ios Like mac
and help me to find my solution please

Answer (score 0):

You can checkout this official documentation from Microsoft to run IOS simulator in Windows and follow the steps here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/tools/ios-simulator/

Comment: Are I Am using visual studio code editor

Comment: and android emultor for windows  now help me

Comment: Have you followed the steps mentioned here  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/tools/ios-simulator/. ?

Comment: Its difficult please give me quick easy solution

Comment: Or youtube link for my query What is your whatappsnumber